# How can I upgrade Python to a specific version?

Tags: python

I am currently working on Python 2.6.5 and I would like to upgrade to Python 2.6.6.

Is there a way I can do so?

Comment: Note, Python 2.6.7 is the most recent Python 2.6 release but Python 2.6 is now in security-fix-only mode. Consider upgrading to Python 2.7.x, which is in bug-fix-only mode, or, eventually, to Python 3.

Comment: I also suggest upgrading to 2.7.2. If you want a constant environment, independant of the OS's Python distribution, use virtualenv. You can put your version of python and it's required libraries in a virtualenv.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the appropriate installer (or, if they don't have one for your OS, source code) from http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/.  Instructions from there will depend on your operating system, but I'm guessing you can handle it.  (Plus, they have install instructions.)

Answer (score 10):

In Linux:

1. Select the version that you're looking for: https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. From the appropriate version's page, copy the download link. (eg. `https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/Python-3.8.3.tgz`)
3. Go to the directory you want to download the compressed package to and run `wget "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/Python-3.8.3.tgz"`
4. In that same directory, run `tar -zxvf Python-3.8.3.tgz` to extract Python
5. `cd` into the directory where Python has been extracted to
6. Run `./configure`
7. Run `make`
8. Run `make install`
9. Run `python --version` to check that the installation was successful

Python should now be installed at the desired version.

Comment: When I ran the commands, I need to run with "sudo" in step 8 "make install", else there is a permission issue. And with sudo, I met the error "zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available", so I had to run "sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev". Finally the installation is successful.